# Using WPF what is the most scalable Automated UI framework for testing?

Tags: c#, software-testing, wpf

A number of frameworks are available for automated WPF testing. Some of the examples include:

- CodedUI tests
- WinAppDriver
- FlaUI

Which framework is best suited for performing automated WPF tests in terms of scale. I believe all the frameworks do not support parallel testing. So assuming running multiple VM's is the preferred option?

Comment: [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. For example, apart from scaling, what features do you need? What licenses are acceptable? How much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid options?

Answer (score 0):

We use coded ui heavily in my team for 8 years. It is running 4000 tests on machines and vms.

It takes a while to master it.

I heard food comments are Ranroex as well